# Yield-to-maturity (YTM) vs effective annual rate (EAR)

Tags: interest-rates, finance, bond, finance-mathematics, bond-yields

If the yield-to-maturity (YTM) on a bond is 5%, is the effective annual rate (EAR) on the cash flows associated with the bond also 5%?

I know that YTM does account for the present value of a bond's future coupon payments. Does the effective annual rate on cash flows associated with a bond not reflect this?

Comment: The yields of US Govt bonds are based on *semi-annual* compounding, the EAR calculation converts it to an equivalent *annual* rate (so it is going to be slightly higher than 5%, namely -1+(1+0.05/2)^2 = 5.0625%